# How to give action to selected combo box

Tags: javascript, html

[Hi, i want to use search by id and search by date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bYjB.png)

```
<select id="menu">
    <option value="<?=site_url('web/execute_search')?>">By Id</a></option>
    <option value="<?=site_url('web/execute_searchs')?>">By Date</a></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I have combo box, when i select search by id and submit so it will go to  Controller ('web/execute_search') , then if i select date and submit, go to Controller ('web/execute_search').

Comment: You'll need javascript and a change event for that. Give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<select id="menu" onchange="option()">
    <option value="1" content="1">By Id</a></option>
    <option value="2" content="2">By Date</a></option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

then here's javascript:

```
<script>function option(){
var x = document.getElementById("menu").value;
if (x==1){
    window.location.href = "execute_search";
}
if (x==2){
window.location.href = "execute_searchs";
}}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function findID()
{

     var e = document.getElementById("menu");
     var clicked = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
     var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
      if(clicked ==1)
      {
      window.location.href = "web/execute_search";
      }
      if (clicked ==2)
      {
      window.location.href= "web/execute_searchs";
      }
     alert(clicked); 
     alert(text);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="menu" name="menu">
    <option value="1">By Id</option>
    <option value="2">By Date</option>
</select>
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="findID();" />

</body>
</html>
```

used `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;` to get the value.
used `e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;` to get the text, means the way you want to sort.

Hope it will help you!!